# java.sql.Time : insert current time correctly

Tags: java, spring, java-time

I'm trying to insert current time into a `java.sql.Time` field, but I get this exception:

```
default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.sql.Time' for property 'entryDate'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.sql.Time] for value ''; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException]
```

This is the code:

```
firm.setEntryDate(Time.valueOf(java.time.LocalDate.now().toString()));
```

Can anybody please advise what I am doing wrong? Thanks!

Update: Firm.class

```
@JsonProperty("webshow")
private String webShow;
private Time entryDate;

public String getWebShow () {
    return webShow;
}

public void setWebShow (String webShow) {
    this.webShow = webShow;
}

public Time getEntryDate () {
    return entryDate;
}

public void setEntryDate (Time entryDate) {
    this.entryDate = entryDate;
}
```

Full exception:

```
 Resolved exception caused by Handler execution: org.springframework.validation.BindException: org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors
Field error in object 'firm' on field 'entryDate': rejected value []; codes [typeMismatch.firm.entryDate,typeMismatch.entryDate,typeMismatch.java.sql.Time,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [firm.entryDate,entryDate]; arguments []; default message [entryDate]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.sql.Time' for property 'entryDate'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.sql.Time] for value ''; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException]
```

Comment: try removing `.toString()` and see

Comment: @niceman `firm.setEntryDate(Time.valueOf(java.time.LocalTime.now()));` I had to change it to LocalTime instead of LocalDate

Comment: @niceman it is inside `Time.valueOf` which expect a string

Comment: Are you sur it's actually that line that throws, and not something inside `firm.setEntryDate`?

Comment: @litelite like what? :)

Comment: @DenissM. like some line attempting to do the conversion in the method. Can you post the code for it?

Comment: The error message says it all. `Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.sql.Time' for property 'entryDate';`

Comment: `firm.setEntryDate(Time.valueOf(java.time.LocalTime.now()));` this line also gives the same error. Very strange.

Comment: @litelite updated initial post.

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with your setter. It seems that spring is trying to convert something. What is it converting?

Comment: @RealSkeptic I don't know yet. I included the whole exception above in initial post.

Comment: `Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.sql.Time] for value ''` sounds like it is trying to convert an empty string.

Comment: @OleV.V. you're right, it's getting this data from a thymeleaf form and it is empty there. I need to generate this data on the form then before submitting it to backend.

Comment: Outside the box, could you change the type of `entryDate` to `LocalTime`?? If so, I think it could have other positive consequences. I never liked `java.sql.Time`.

Comment: So, your question is not about time formats, but rather about how to make a thymeleaf field mandatory, or how to set a default value when it is empty.

Comment: @RealSkeptic not really. Thymeleaf was passing a null field of entryDate and Spring was converting it to string for Time. I don't think I have this problem with LocalTime now. Checking

Comment: @OleV.V. well now the backend is throwing a lot of errors.. like `Can not construct instance of java.time.LocalTime: no suitable constructor found, can not deserialize from Object value (missing default constructor or creator, or perhaps need to add/enable type information?)`

Comment: @OleV.V. :) there is no date coming in from thymeleaf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
firm.setEntryDate(java.sql.Time.valueOf(LocalTime.now()));
```

Answer (score -1):

Use timeStamp

private TimeStamp entryDate;

Comment: TimeStamp? There is only TIMESTAMP (oracle specific) and Timestamp.